# How can a blackbody emit more energy than it has?

Tags: thermal-radiation

Okay. This is going to be a weird one.

Imagine that, for some reason, and through some incredible means, you've managed to heat a human up to over one tredicillion Kelvin (10^42 K)

I'm trying to figure out how much energy they will emit as blackbody radiation, so that I can figure out how much energy they're losing and we can 'top them up' with the sufficient energy to remain at that temperature.

Again, don't ask. I need it for a thing...

The specific heat capacity equation tells us that this object will have:

```
Eh = cmΔT
Eh = 4180 (humans are mostly water so i used water's value) x 85kg x 1.8x10^42 K
Comes out to around 6.6 x 10^47 Joules (I didn't write all the significant figures so value may change if you're plugging in numbers but it's roughly that order of magnitude)
```

So that's the amount of heat energy the person has in total.

To calculate the radiated energy of a blackbody, there's the equation (I may be wrong. I learned this just today from good ol' internet)

```
q = σ T^4 A ε
Where sigma is the Stefan-Boltzmann Constant,
T is the temperature 
A is the area
Epsilon is the emissivity of the person
```

When I plug in the numbers it gives me a ridiculously large number. Of course it does. We're raising a tredicillion to the 4th power!

This seems to suggest that it's radiating 10^160 - ish Watts of Power. That's much more than the amount of heat energy it has. How is this possible?

Is it something to do with emitting the radiation over time? They're going to be in this situation for an hour, if that number helps. (don't ask why I set someone on fire at 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 Kelvin for a whole hour)

So how do I actually find out how much energy they're going to lose? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A note on terminology : emission is power, not energy.

Comment: *10^160 - ish Watts of Power. That's much more than the amount of heat energy it has* You can’t compare power to energy. Do you understand the definition of power?

Comment: *heat a human up to over one tredicillion Kelvin* This is impossible. Fantasy physics is off-topic here.

Comment: There is no such thing as a total amount of heat that an object can have. You need to first understand this to understand how engines work.

Answer (score 2):

Power isn't energy.   It's energy per time.    You can run 5 meters per second without running 5 meters.

Likewise you can emit 500 J/s without emitting 500 J.  In both cases, you must slow down or stop what you're doing before one second has elapsed.

> So how do I actually find out how much energy they're going to lose?

Ignore the heat capacity.  All you care is the emitted power multiplied by the time it's emitting it.  That's what they're losing, so it needs to be replenished.

Basically this is telling you that a smallish object at such a temperature would cool down very, *very* quickly unless that much power is being fed to it.  The heat capacity is for all intents and purposes, zero at this scale.

Comment: Okay. So if Power is Energy/ time, then to get the total energy it will lose you take that power and multiply by 3600? (60 seconds per minute and 60 mins per hour)

Comment: You multiply it for however long you want it to be at that temperature.  For an hour, you don't multiply by 3600, you multiply by 3600 *seconds*. 

1 watt * 1 second = 1 joule.